# How do I calculate the contents of the input bar? - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a formula I want to apply to the calculate button so when clicked it runs the input number through my function and displays the result of it.
I have the input bar and the button, but what do I need to make the button respond to the content in the input bar?

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        
        <form>
          <label>
              Total
                  <input type="text" name="name" />
          </label>
                   <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
        </form>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi!
You should head to [reactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) first. They are very clear and easy to follow

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for any input, make a state. 
Then, you can use the onSubmit attribute on the `<form>` element to call your method. 
To display input, you just simply use the state.

For examples, you can find them at the official docs, https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {    this.setState({value: event.target.value});  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

### Functional Component

```
function NameForm(props) {
     const [value, setValue] = useState("");
     
     const handleChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);
     const handleSubmit = (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
         console.log("Form was submitted with input " + value);
     };
     
     return (
         <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              Name:
              <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />        
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
         </form>
     )
}
```

Comment: Outstanding, thank you very much, and have a great day!

Comment: @TheDude09 I've added a functional version of the official example incase you need it

Comment: Literally, a saint, thank you so much.